# Can I use the value for one key in Info.plist inside the value of another Info.plist key?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

I'd like to use the value for 'Bundle display name' (CFBundleDisplayName) inside the value of another Info.plist key (NSContactsUsageDescription).

I tried the following, but this does not work:

```
${CFBundleDisplayName} must access your Address Book to input the scanned contact
information. ${CFBundleDisplayName} will never access your Address Book for marketing
or advertising purposes.
```

Does anybody know how to do that?

Addendum: The solution should also work when localizing the value.

Comment: Are you sure that `CFBundleDisplayName` is defined? Does it work with `CFBundleName`?

Comment: You could try to rephrase your description to avoid the app name. This is the description, not the title of the message, as far as I know. "AppName would like to access your contacts" will be the automatic title already. After that you could add "Your contacts will never be accessed for marketing or advertising purposes."

Comment: Both are defined, but neither of them work. ${PRODUCT_NAME} works, but due to a name change, I explicitly require CFBundleDisplayName.

Comment: Thanks also for your second comment, DrummerB, that's a good idea. However, I hope marketing division agrees, too, and gives me an okay for that phrasing, or marketing comes up with another purpose string without the App Name.

Answer (score 6):

Using the `${VARIABLE}` you can only reference build settings, but not other values in your Info.plist. Try adding a new user-defined build setting and use that. Go to the **Build Settings** tab and click **Add Build Setting** in the bottom right corner.

Comment: Yes, this works. However, I forgot to mention, that I also need to localize the value of NSContactsUsageDescription. I've got another SO question on that and didn't wanted to mix the two things. However, adding a build setting won't work together with localization through InfoPlist.strings.

Comment: Any solution with localization?

Comment: @ShebinKoshy You can [localize the Info.plist file](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-102276).